# Flutter project gradle build errors

Tags: flutter, build.gradle, flutter-dependencies

Please help me to remove these two errors

1. "new Properties()"   2. "GradleException()"
   I have attached a picture.

   [image]

Please help me to solve this error
I found the solution but fail to get the results.

Comment: the exception is already telling you what to do. `Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file`

Answer (score 0):

You can ignore these errors. Your project will work just fine.